# Number of Dispersion Lines in A Square Dot Matrix

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, elementary-number-theory

I want to find a formula to calculate the number of dispersion lines I can draw from any one corner of a square dot matrix of size $n \times n$.

By dispersion lines, I mean the lines that connect a particular point to all other points in a dot diagram. Here's a picture of what I mean :

[image: Diagram]

(That's an approximate diagram of what I mean; sorry for the crude diagram)
Here, the horizontal blue line on the top row (when considered a straight line) connects many dots to a single point (thus all those dots on the line are collinear), so when we count the number of dispersion lines, we have to count lines connecting many collinear points as one and we mustn't take the subunits into consideration.

So when we consider a square dot matrix, where the dots are arranged as a square, we can draw $3$ apparent dispersion lines, plus some more. What I would like to find is a formula to calculate the number of dispersion lines in square dot grids (or dot matrices).
What I have at hand is this one formula that I tried to formulate today:$$n^2 - (n + 2(n - 1)) + 3$$
The problem is that this formula isn't working for all values of $n$ (I mean, the number of dots in a column/row of the square dot matrix), and also I haven't been able to spend sufficient time to find the number of dispersion lines for $n > 5$. If asked for, I'll attach the numbers below.

Any help in formulating an accurate formula is appreciated. If such a formula exists, please do tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Euclid's orchard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_orchard)

Comment: @JeanMarie , I'll try checking it out..

Comment: @JeanMarie , I am immature to understand all that.. maybe a simpler thing would suffice...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $n=5$, the slopes of lines are in ascending order

$${\color{red}{0},\color{blue}{\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3},\frac{3}{4},}\color{red}{1},\color{green}{\frac{4}{3},\frac{3}{2},2,3,4,}\color{red}{\infty}}$$

where blue and green are reciprocal of each other (symmetry about principal diagonal), hence equal in number.

Observe green slopes can be grouped as
$$ \color{green}{\underbrace{\frac{4}{3},\frac{4}{1}},\underbrace{\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{1}},\underbrace{\frac{2}{1}}}$$

where numerators run from $2$ to $4$ and denominators are respectively coprime to numerators.

In general, this series runs from $i=2$ to $i=n-1$ and counts for all integers less than $i$ and coprime to it. We have [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) to count this, it is simply $\varphi(i)$.

Hence desired number of dispersion lines is $$f(n) = 
 \color{red}{3} + \color{green}{2\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}} \color{green}{\varphi(i)} $$

We get following values

- $n=2$, $f(n) = 3$
- $n=3$, $f(n) = 5$
- $n=4$, $f(n) = 9$
- $n=5$, $f(n) = 13$
- $n=6$, $f(n) = 21$
- $n=7$, $f(n) = 25$

$f(n)$ satisfies the recurrence relation $$f(n) = f(n-1) + 2\varphi(n-1)$$

Comment: is this what's in Euclid's Orchard ? I am a $10^{\text{th}}$ grader, so I have no idea of such stuff.

Comment: I'm not well familiar with Euclid's Orchard problem. Euler's totient function is taught in elementary Number theory.

Comment: I haven't learnt all that, so I confused this with an article JeanMarie put in the comments below my question.

Comment: Will this be of any use in solving Brocard's problem ? (Please check what it is in Wikipedia)

Comment: Just by the statement of Brocard's problem, I'm not able to generate any insight related to above argument.

Comment: You don't know about Euler's totient function, but you're asking about Brocard's problem? Look – the trouble with Number Theory is that it has a lot of problems that anyone can understand, but that no one can solve. It has other problems anyone can understand, but it takes a math degree to understand the solution. It's very easy to bite off more than you can chew. If you're interested in this sort of problem, there's no escaping it: you're going to have to sit yourself down and learn a lot of (fun) math. Get an intro Number Theory text, and start reading!

Comment: @cosmo5 Why I asked this question on dispersion lines is because I found that the difference between $n^2$ and the number of dispersion lines seemed to follow an AP at first, then broke off from $n = 5$. So, if we can find such $n$ where the AP is broken, we may be able to find the other Brown numbers.

Comment: @GerryMyerson , I understand that, but I have to manage time for that too. I am bad at time management ':)

Comment: As @GerryMyerson pointed out, please make yourself more thorough in Number theory, so you develop more tools and understanding necessary to attack the bigger problems. They're unsolved for a reason - for the depth they encompass, please understand that.

Comment: In "Euler's Orchard", you can ask, how many of the trees are visible from a corner of the orchard. This is the same as asking how many lines you can draw from the corner, so it's the same as your problem.

Comment: @GerryMyerson , Thanks !

Comment: I don't know what "Brown numbers" are.

Comment: @GerryMyerson , they are the numbers that satisfy Brocard's problem, and only $3$ pairs of them have been found. I am trying to find if many more of them exist or not.

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia essay on Brocard's problem? It seems it has been checked that there are no more out to a quadrillion. I don't see any connection to Euclid's Orchard. (which is what I meant went I wrote "Euler's Orchard" a few comments ago).

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I think there is and it is I who want to confirm stuff :)

Comment: @cosmo5 I asked in OEIS a sequence beginning by 3,5,9,13,21,25,.. : I obtained this [answer](https://oeis.org/A058989) mentionning "J. D. Laison and M. Schick, Seeing dots: visibility of lattice points, Mathematics Magazine, Vol. 80 (2007), pp. 274-282. See page 281 reference 13"... Please note the keywords "lattice points visibility" giving many Google interesting hits.

Comment: Thank you, @JeanMarie!